# Assistive technology for writing music

Tags: music-composing

I am looking for a computer program or app that can write music for a certain composer.

The composer can figure out the correct notes when played to him. If you play him a C and a D, he will tell you the correct note is a C. He cannot, however, play them on a keyboard or other device due to dexterity issues. After determining the correct notes (say, C A A G C A A G) the composer then wants the notes played back to him, and preferably saved as a music file.

Which programs can he use to create music?

(Web based programs would be more convenient than downloads. And free resources are preferred, of course.)

Comment: You wrote that the composer can not use a keyboard or other device. Does that mean the composer has to speak aloud "C A A G C A A G" and the software has to do speech recognition to recognize the notes?